# How can I solve my system of two simultaneous equations?

Tags: equation-solving

How to solve the system

```
{b - a*Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1] - a^2*(a*b - Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1]) == 0,  
 a - b*Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1] - b^2*(a*b - Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1]) == 0}
```

The command

```
Solve[{b - a*Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1] - a^2*(a*b - Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1]) == 0, 
       a - b*Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1] - b^2*(a*b - Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1]) == 0}
      , 
      {a, b}, Complexes]
```

produces, in particular,

> ```
> {b -> -(a/(1 + a))}
> ```

which gives the wrong answer if $a=1.$  The answer obtained by the command

```
Reduce[{b - a*Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1] - a^2*(a*b - Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1]) == 0,
        a - b*Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1] - b^2*(a*b - Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1]) == 0}
       ,
       {a, b}, Complexes]
```

also seems untrue in the last term

> ```
> (a (1 + a) (-1 + a - a^2 + a^3) != 0 && 
> 0 == (1/(1 + a))(-1 - a - a^2 - Sqrt[(1 + a + a^2)^2/(1 + a)^2] - 
>  a Sqrt[(1 + a + a^2)^2/(1 + a)^2]) && b == -(a/(1 + a))).
> ```

Comment: Seems to be similar issue like [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32246/5478) take a look at comments. Please post Mathematica code in code blocks instead od LaTeX form.

Comment: @ Kuba: Thank you for your interest to the question. A new moment consists in the partially untrue answer (at least, in my opinion) obtained by the Reduce command. I am a newcomer and I don't know how to insert a Mathematica code. Where is this written?

Comment: @ Kuba: It is very kind of you!

Comment: You are welcome. I like when posts are transparent :) Now you know how to do this in the future.

Comment: @ Kuba: Could you briefly explain how to insert a Mathematica code or give a reference concerning it?

Comment: Sure, take a look at [editing-help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help). If you are going to stay around, what I highly recommend! :), you may be interested in [how to easily copy MMA code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/484/5478) and similar topics here or on meta.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this will be marked as duplicate, but to let the OP carry on with his/her work, @Kuba's comment is warranted, and `Verifysolutions` is needed in this case

```
sys = {a - b Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1] - b^2 (a b - Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1]) == 0,
 b - a Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1] - a^2 (a b - Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1]) == 0}
soln = Solve[sys, {a, b}, VerifySolutions -> True]
sys /. soln
(*{{True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, 
  True}, {True, True}, {True, True}} *)
```

With respect to the first solution you obtained, b=-a/(1+a), here is the comment from [the similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32246/)

> If you set b=−2, then a=−b(b+1)=2−1=−2 and not +2. This holds for any
>   pair of real numbers given b<−1. Use Reduce in place of Solve and the
>   a=−b(b+1) solution will come with a constraint that, in the real
>   domain, translates to b<−1.

I assume, although haven't confirmed, that your problem falls into a similar category.

Comment: Are you serious? Pay attention to the  Complexes domain in Solve and Reduce.

Comment: Adding `Complexes` to `Solve` doesn't change the solution generated: `Solve[sys, {a, b}, VerifySolutions -> True] === 
 Solve[sys, {a, b}, Complexes, VerifySolutions -> True]` so if I'm missing something here, perhaps you could clarify your question.

Comment: Do you pay attention to the "Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables." warning. Also how about the Reduce command?

Answer (score 1):

The solution returned by `Reduce` seems to be correct:

```
sys = {a - b Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1] - b^2 (a b - Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1]) == 
    0, b - a Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1] - a^2 (a b - Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 1]) == 
    0};
soln = Reduce[sys, {a, b}, Complexes];
List @@ soln[[-1]] /. a -> 1 // Simplify
```

> {False, False, b == -(1/2)}

Both conditions give `False` for your problematic case, so this solution does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

Just to facilitate:

`Solve` yields:

```
{{y -> -(x/(1 + x))}, {x -> 1, y -> -I}, {x -> 1, y -> I}, {x -> 1, 
  y -> 1}, {x -> 0, y -> 0}, {x -> I, y -> I}, {x -> -I, 
  y -> 1}, {x -> I, y -> 1}}
```

(with warning).

Just concentrating on the real solutions, it is evident the real solutions can be seen in the following)

```
f[x_, y_] := 
 x - y Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + 1] - y^2 (x y - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + 1])
Plot3D[{f[x, y], f[y, x]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {f[#1, #2] &, f[#2, #1] &}, Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
 MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Green}}]
ContourPlot[{x - y Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + 1] - 
   y^2 (x y - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + 1]), 
  y - x Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + 1] - 
   x^2 (x y - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + 1])}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 Contours -> {{0.}}, ContourShading -> False]
```

In the second plot I truncated the range to avoid the plotting of point related to asymptotics.

[image]

[image]